# How to create DB tables in this case?

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a table called "users" which is having

1. userID (primary key)
2. username
3. password
4. name

so now scenario is each user can have n-number of categories which mean userID=1 may have category1, category2, category3 so on and again each categories may have n-number of sub categories. So how can I design my tables? Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you post what you tried ?

Comment: i am new to development and i need to create tables in db where the above scenario should match. i mean how to populate list of categories created by user in his record.

Comment: I think you need to start with a good tutorial for mysql and database concepts

Comment: here is a good place where to start http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sql-for-beginners--net-8200

Comment: scenarios can be explained once to people who are really new into it. so that people like me can get ideas instead searching for it for all the day. and point is all online tutorials are explaining concepts and how it works but not ideas like this (where i am lacking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, the proposed DB Design could be like the following

```
 1. tbl_users(uid, uname, password, Name, ...)
 2. tbl_categories(cid, cname, parent_category_id ...) -- self join
 3. tbl_user_categories (uid, cid) -- Mapping table
```

*Some Notes:*

- Having sensitive information like *user names*,*passwords* and names and other details in one table is not advisable.
- It is better start learning using some good tutorials over internet to understand DB concepts
- stackoverflow is for specific coding or other specific technical problems you struck with, not for asking DB designs.